# PHP - stream_filter_append, unable to locate filter (mcrypt)

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

My config is (from phpinfo()):

```
PHP Version 5.3.10
Registered Stream Filters: convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.* 

mcrypt support: enable
mcrypt_filter support: enable
Version: 2.5.8
Supported ciphers: cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes: cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream
```

So you see I have enabled mcrypt.

I try

```
mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'ofb', '');
```

and it's ok.

But when I try something like

```
stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.rijndael-256', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
```

I have two warnings

```
stream_filter_append(): Could not open encryption module in ...
stream_filter_append(): unable to create or locate filter &quot;mcrypt.rijndael-256&quot; in ...
```

I guess it's wrong to write

```
stream_filter_append($fp, 'rijndael-256', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts); // without 'mcrypt.*'
```

but in this case I have only one warning

```
stream_filter_append(): unable to create or locate filter &quot;rijndael-256&quot; in ...
```

And the last thing. Encryption/description with "rot13" works well

```
stream_filter_append($fp, "string.rot13", STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
```

So the question is how to encrypt/decrypt with some of the mcrypt methods?

Comment: a) no idea why it failes, but b) just something I've seen before quite often, so just in case: rijndael-256 is not aes256. aes256 is still rijndael-128 with a 32 byte/256bit key.

Comment: What it indicates is that the requested cipher method is not available. You have either a typo, or one of the ciphers(rijndael-256) is not compiled into your version of mcrypt.so.

Comment: @ kamlesh.bar ....but then again mcrypt_module_open works and the necessary ciphers and modes are in the output of phpinfo(), that's the strange part - as long as the phpinfo() and the stream_filter_append() script have been executed by the "same" php instance (and not one as a webserver module and one via php-cli -> different php.ini files)

Comment: try getting all filter and apply one of them 
$streamlist = stream_get_filters();
print_r($streamlist);

Comment: @ kamlesh.bar. The result is Array ( [0] => convert.iconv.* [1] => mcrypt.* [2] => mdecrypt.* [3] => string.rot13 [4] => string.toupper [5] => string.tolower [6] => string.strip_tags [7] => convert.* [8] => consumed [9] => dechunk [10] => zlib.* [11] => bzip2.* )... As I mentioned in the question "string.rot13" works well and other methods from this list works well too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I lost sight of some important details.
One more string:

```
$opts = array('iv' => $iv, 'key' => $key, 'mode' => 'stream');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.rijndael-256', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
```

And of course it fails because Rijndael-256 not supported in STREAM mode.
So thank you for your comments and please sorry to trouble you.